# Using Blender to convert a .ply file

Tags: .fbx

I have a .ply file of Abraham Lincoln.

This is how it first looks when I import it to Blender:

[image]

I can see it includes color because I am able to switch to Vertex Paint mode and see this:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to convert this .ply file to a .fbx file so that when I import the .fbx file to another software (like Unity for example), I will be able to see a **colorful** object.

Can anyone here tell me whether this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FBX does support vertex color. Unity supports this but needs to be setup in whatever shader. The setup in other softwares is off topic for this forum. glTF supports vertex color as well.
You can also view vertex color in object mode with the "^" icon next to the shading modes with this menu:
aa [image]

And edit and select Vertex colors here(properties<Object Data Properties<ColorAttributes)